# Undefined variable '$imageName' Laravel 9

Tags: php, laravel

In my controller I have two methods:

```
public function uploadCropImage(Request $request, $imageName)
{
    $folderPath = public_path('upload/');
    $image_parts = explode(";base64,", $request->image);
    $image_type_aux = explode("image/", $image_parts[0]);
    $image_type = $image_type_aux[1];
    $image_base64 = base64_decode($image_parts[1]);
    $imageName = uniqid() . '.png';
    $imageFullPath = $folderPath . $imageName;
    file_put_contents($imageFullPath, $image_base64);
    return response()->json(['success'=>'Crop Image Uploaded Successfully']);
}

 public function store(Request $request)
{
    $input = $request->all();
    $input['photo'] = $imageName;
    User::create($input);
}
```

How can I pass value of variable "$imageName" in other method("store")?

Comment: did you have an example where this two function are used?

Comment: I just want to pass value of variable $imageName from first method to second..

Comment: the most simple is to edit your store function definition to accept a second parameter

Comment: Yes but how to code that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to upload image, take image name and then give to photo column. I suggest you to use [helper functions](https://dev.to/kingsconsult/how-to-create-laravel-8-helpers-function-global-function-d8n).
You can use helper function for image uploading and then return `$imageName` from it. And then you just give to photo column.

Here's a demonstration:

```
public function uploadCropImage(Request $request, $imageName)
{
    $folderPath = public_path('upload/');
    $image_parts = explode(";base64,", $request->image);
    $image_type_aux = explode("image/", $image_parts[0]);
    $image_type = $image_type_aux[1];
    $image_base64 = base64_decode($image_parts[1]);
    $imageName = uniqid() . '.png';
    $imageFullPath = $folderPath . $imageName;
    file_put_contents($imageFullPath, $image_base64);

    // You return $imageName from helper function
    return $imageName;
}
```

You just use `$imageName` from helper function and return response in from `store()` method.

Comment: "Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\CropImageController::store(), 1 passed in"

Comment: Can you show inside of your store function with it's parameters?